I want to speak to whoever /whomever is in charge
whoever (subject)

The person or people who; any person who
it does not matter who

whomever(object)

when whatever person or people is/are the object of a sentence.


I want to speak to whoever is in charge.
I want to speak to whomever is in charge.

I think the second is correct because the subject wants to speak to the person, who is the object.

I'm interested to hear from the grammarians, because "whom" is supposed to be used for the object of a sentence. I expect the proper usage is whomever.

@MichaelCurtis - believe me, educated older British speaker, nobody says 'whomever'.

Everybody would use: To whom it may concern.

Note the declining use of 'whom' over the last 200 years.

In both BrE and AmE "to whoever" is used much more than "to whomever" over the years. "to whomever" is mostly used in Fiction, followed by TV/Movies and then newspaper and magazines. In BrE "to whomever" is hardly used, even if it is used it is used in Fiction and in Academic writings.

The first is not wrong, because if it works with whom, it works with who
Who/whom is, put simply, a can of worms that really should stay shut. If you want to know whether you can use "whom" or not, ask the question and see if the answer is "him/her/them" or not
If it is, then go use "whom", if not it's "who"
put simply:
he -> who
him -> whom
E.g.:
"Whom did you bring to start this whole mess?" "I brought him!"
Instead of taking this mental burden tho, it's far easier to just... use "who", which works in everything "whom" would be used in, and then some!

+1. As you say, just use 'who'.
